# Why my pagination is gone when i use scroller: True

Tags: datatables

My datatable code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#globaldatatable').DataTable({
            scrollX: '100%',
            deferRender: 'true',
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            scroller: {
                loadingIndicator: 'true'

            },
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'excelHtml5', className: 'excelButton' },
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', className: 'excelButton' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I'm setting scroller to true, why the pagination and per page data selector is gone? how to enable it?

Comment: What happens if you reduce your example similar to the examples on http://datatables.net/extras/scroller?

Answer (score 0):

I believe using scroller plugin makes your datatable scrollable(

> **Features**
>
> Key features of Scroller include:
>
> - Speed! The aim of Scroller for DataTables is to make rendering large    data sets fast
> - Full compatibility with DataTables' deferred rendering    for maximum    speed
> - **Display millions of rows in a scrollable table**
> - Integration with state saving in DataTables (scrolling position is       saved)
> - Easy to use

) and disables pagination buttons.

this is the working example of a scroller plugin

https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: so i cant use pagination with scroller at same time?

Comment: Actually, pagination is pre-requisite of scroller plugin(_pagination needs to be **true**_ for it to work) , however, pagination button was disabled because it will conflict with each other. If you really want to hava a scroll in your table, you can use the `scrollY` function of datatable.